# NatTable sorting with custom comparator

Tags: java, nattable

I was looking at the (509_SortHeaderLayer.java) example as a reference point.

I add a custom comparator directly to the SortedList as shown in the example below. However, when I click on columns in the debugger, my custom comparator never reaches a breakpoint I set in the first line of my compare() method.

If I add the comparator as an AbstractRegistryConfiguration it works as expected (the breakpoint is reached when I click on a column).

Why does setting the comparator in the SortedLists constructor not work as I expected? Some general code snippets are shown below:

```
public void setSortComparatorWorks() {
    SortedList<T> sortedList = new SortedList<>(eventList, null);
    init(sortedList);
    getNatTable().addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {

        @Override
        public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(SortConfigAttributes.
              SORT_COMPARATOR, new MyComparator<T>(),  
              DisplayMode.NORMAL);
        }
    });
    getNatTable().configure();
}

public void setSortComparatorDoesntWork() {
    SortedList<T> sortedList = new SortedList<>(eventList, 
      new MyComparator<T>);
    init(sortedList);
    getNatTable().configure();
}

private void init(SortedList sortedList){
    this.bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(sortedList, 
      columnPropertyAccessor);

    this.bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(this.bodyDataProvider);

    this.bodyLayerStack = new DefaultBodyLayerStack(new 
      GlazedListsEventLayer<>(this.bodyDataLayer, eventList));

    this.columnHeaderLayerStack = new 
      GlazedListsColumnHeaderLayerStack<>(
        columnHeaderDataProvider, sortedList,
        columnPropertyAccessor, configRegistry, this.bodyLayerStack);

    this.sortHeaderLayer = new SortHeaderLayer<>(columnHeaderLayerStack,
      new GlazedListsSortModel<T>(sortedList, 
      columnPropertyAccessor, configRegistry, bodyDataLayer),
      false);

    setChildLayer(GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER, sortHeaderLayer, 0, 0);
    setChildLayer(GridRegion.BODY, bodyLayerStack, 0, 1);

    getNatTable().addConfiguration(new SingleClickSortConfiguration());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work as you expect, because the internal function will replace any existing `Comparator` on the `SortedList` with a `Comparator` that is derived out of the `ConfigRegistry` and the current applied sort state.

BTW, interesting that you refer to `_509_SortHeaderLayerExample` while an example with GlazedLists is `_602_GlazedListsSortingExample`.

Comment: I am a bit confused... If I add the comparator in the constructor and I do not add one to the ConfigRegistry, why does it still not work? This is demonstrated in the xample above in the setSortComparatorDoesntWork method.  I did not see the 602 example, I will check that out as well.

Comment: As I already said, it will be derived. And even if you don't set one yourself, you add one by using the SingleClickSortConfiguration, which is a DefaultSortConfiguration.